# nopCommerce - Is is possible to make changes from Code First approach to model First?

Tags: nopcommerce

I recently started digging into nopCommerce and from their blog I found out that It's a Code First approach development. But, I want make changes from code first approach to model First Approach. 
Is it possible? and how to that?

Thank You

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but I recommend you reading this article: http://www.pronopcommerce.com/using-entity-framework-ef-code-first-migrations-in-nopcommerce-for-fast-customizations which might give you some inspiration.